# How do I copy repo outside of docker app i'm building for?

Tags: docker

My directory structure looks like...

```
src
   repo_1
      file.py
      file2.py
      Dockerfile
   repo_2
      somefile.sh
      somefile2.sh
```

repo_1 is the app I need to run in the Docker container I'm building.  repo_2 has some bash scripts I need to run in the Dockerfile.

Currently Dockerfile has..

```
WORKDIR /usr/app/src
COPY ..
```

When I build repo_1 files are in /usr/app/src as expected.  What i want is to copy both repo_1 and repo_2 files into a directory like the directory structure shown above.  How do I do this?

Comment: You need to set the build-context directory to the parent directory, and then refer to `repo_1` and `repo_2` subdirectories explicitly.  You can't ever `COPY` from outside the build-context directory.